# Precision of measurements and of a number

Tags: numerical-methods

I know the definitions of both the precision of measurements and that of an approximate number (sort of). I want to know how they relate to each other. I understand the relationship between the accuracy of a measurement and that of an approximate number.

Edit : Measurements are said to be more precise if they differ less among themselves. The precision of an approximate number is determined by the position of its right-most significant figure.

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you are asking and what you want to know. I recommend that you include the definitions that you know. Otherwise, I fear that it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: You have not provided a valid definition.There are multiple valid interpretations of what you want to know. Do you what to know about the law of large numbers? If you are measuring something, say, the length of a rod, then you can *expect* to increase the number of correct significant figures by $1$ every time you increase the number of measurements by a factor of 100.